# c# string constants vs static properies

Tags: c#, performance, constants

I have a class with predefined constant strings which are used as keys to retrieve the data from the external storage by provided key.

```
public class StorageKeys
{
    public const string SomeKey = "Foo";
    public const string AnotherKey = "Foooo";        
}

public interface IStorage
{
    string GetValue(string key);
}
```

Which is used like this:

```
IStorage t = new Storage();
string value = t.GetValue(StorageKeys.SomeKey);
```

It works but I'm concerned that potentiality it's possible to call `GetValue` method with just string argument which can cause an error:

```
string value = t.GetValue("Illegal key");
```

That's why I've come up with this idea:

```
public class StorageKeys
{
    public static StorageKeys SomeKey = new StorageKeys("Foo");
    public static StorageKeys AnotherKey = new StorageKeys("Foooo");

    private StorageKeys(string key)
    {
        _key = key;
    }

    private readonly string _key;

    public static implicit operator string(StorageKeys key) => key._key;
}

public interface IStorage
{
    string GetValue(StorageKeys key);
}
```

After these changes my method can be used only with correct keys but I think it would decrease a performance because of static properties and implicit casting.

So my question is it a good idea?

Am I overconcerned?

How much slower my second approach would be comparing to the first one?

Is there another way to prevent passing wrong arguments?

Comment: So why do you care about someone calling the method with an invalid key? That's their issue to deal with. Just throw them an exception.

Comment: Perhaps you want the functionality of an `enum` instead?

Comment: @musefan - enums aren't limited to only named members. They can take on all possible values of their underlying type, so I don't see that solving the problem here.

Comment: If you care so much about correct keys, wrap the interface and provide `GetFoo` and `GetFoooo` methods.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yeah, good point. But then someone can also do `new StorageKeys("Illegal key");`

Comment: @musefan `enum` is not suitable because there are a lot of restrictions to enum member name. For example, it's not possible to use a dot inside it.

Comment: `enum` would be perfectly reasonable as you could convert the enum to a string (e.g. an attribute on the enum) but it still doesn't stop people passing in random numbers.

Comment: @Roman: Well you can use a description attribute to get around that... but anyway, it's probably not a good idea as it won't stop invalid values (though you can get a default value if they supply an incorrect one). Just go with what David said and don't worry about it, throw an exception for unexpected values, it makes sense

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't want do this because there are a lot of keys(more than 20)

Comment: Use constants or use enums if you're worried about performance and the values are hardcoded.  If you don't mind a little overhead then implement a check or a process like you have now.

Comment: @musefan I believe that using attributes on enum members would be slower because of reflection.

Comment: "How much slower my second approach would be comparing to the first one?" Why ask *us*, instead of *measuring* yourself? Anyway I doubt it´ll make a huge difference - if at all. *Simply chose what works for you*, unless you have a specific problem with that solution. So I guess this question is fairly opinion-based.

Comment: @RomanKoliada: Basically, you either do what Jeroen said and have some sort of strongly typed function/property, or throw an exception. Just pick one and move on

Comment: You've probably already wasted more time on this question than the amount of time your app would save by choosing one of the options you gave above :)

Comment: There is no speed difference, the JIT compiler makes the difference disappear.  There is however a big functional difference, public const declarations are pretty dangerous.  You'll get in trouble when you provide a bug fix that also changes the const values.  Those changes won't affect any other assemblies that use the values, const values are baked-in at compile time.  A public const is only okay for a "manifest constant", one whose value is never expected to change again.  The .NET Framework only has a few of them, Math.Pi is one.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I overconcerned?

Short answer, yes.

What you are trying to do is prevent passing an invalid argument which isn't what you are supposed to do in the first place, you should consider using an enum IF that is possible, that makes it 99.9% typesafe and almost no checks would be required.

In a situation where you need that param to be a string, just perform a validation in `GetValue(string key)` and either return a null if you wish to handle that later or just throw an Exception.

Comment: As I pointed out in the comments, using an enum doesn't save you from needing to perform validation checks. Enums are allowed to take on all possible values of the underlying type, whether or not the enum has a named member with that value.

Comment: You are kinda right, but only way to do it is deliberately cast to that type 
ex: `(StorageKeys)1`

Comment: So, perhaps, your statement that using one would be "100% typesafe" and not require checks is, perhaps, less than entirely correct?

Comment: There you  go :)

Comment: 99.9% still implies it's not likely to happen, but you really don't need to have an explicit cast to get an enum value. There could be reflection code, or probably quite common, deserialisation of JSON/XML usually via some HTTP API.